# Is object oriented exception handling in Perl worth it?

Tags: perl, exception

I recently read ["Object Oriented Exception Handling in Perl"](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2002/11/14/exception.html) Perl.com article. Is there any point to use exceptions in Perl?

Comment: use expceptions or use object oriented exceptions?

Comment: are there normal exception?? or do you mean warn and die?? 

I'm talking about the OO ones/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the article - I learned about oveload module :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/whats-broken-about-exceptions-in-perl  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439966/do-you-use-an-exception-class-in-your-perl-programs-why-or-why-not

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I should note that the article you referenced is old, and that you should now use [Exception::Class](http://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::Class) instead of Error.pm, which is quirky and tends to break (it's what I call "black magick"). I should note that I am now the Error.pm maintainer, but I no longer recommend it or make use of it for my own code.

Comment: I would like to award you a [Disciplined badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) for recommending others not to use your own module.

Comment: Link is broken. Should be [Exception::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exception::Class).

Answer (score 13):

> "is there any point to use exceptions in Perl?"

Yes, I highly recommend reading the "Error Handling" chapter in [Perl Best Practices](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?perl_best_practices) by [Damian Conway](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?damian_conway).

It certainly opened my eyes ;-)

Comment: Link is not working it is giving 404 error!

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely.  If you throw a simple 'die', you really don't have any more information that the *computer* can handle.  For example, I have a test framework which uses Test::Most and that module can allow you to die on test failures.  However, my framework needed to know if I was dying because a test failed or because the code died.  Thus, I threw a Test::Most::Exception and my framework can check the exception type and take appropriate action.

Exceptions are your friend :)

Answer (score 3):

In any programming language, exceptions can allow you to deal with different types of errors in different ways. This can be really useful for keeping track of fine-grained errors in testing and intelligently dealing the recoverable errors within your program. It's not worthwhile for every throwaway program you write, but for things you spend a lot of time developing it can be worth the effort.