# How do I test for an exception type in perl?

Tags: perl, eval, exception, die

How can I check what kind of exception caused the script or `eval` block to terminate?
I need to know the type of error, and where the exception occurred.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503189/object-oriented-exception-handling-in-perl-is-it-worth-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439966/do-you-use-an-exception-class-in-your-perl-programs-why-or-why-not and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/whats-broken-about-exceptions-in-perl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The Perl way

Idiomatic Perl is that we are either ignoring all errors or capturing them for logging or forwarding elsewhere:

```
eval { func() };  # ignore error
```

or:

```
eval { func() };
if ($@) {
    carp "Inner function failed: $@";
    do_something_with($@);
}
```

or (using [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny) - see that page for reasons why you might want to use it over Perl's built-in exception handling):

```
try { func() }
catch {
     carp "Inner function failed: $_";
     do_something_with($_);
};
```

If you want to check the type of exception, use regexes:

```
if ( $@ =~ /open file "(.*?)" for reading:/ ) {
    # ...
}
```

The line and file is also in that string too.

This is pretty nasty though, because you have to know the exact string. If you really want good error handling, use an exception module from [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

### Exception::Class

$@ doesn't have to be a string, it can be an object. [Exception::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception::Class) lets you declare and throw exception objects Java-style. You can pass arbitrary information (filename, etc.) with the error when you throw it and get that information out using object methods rather than regex parsing - including the *file* and *line number* of the exception.

If you're using a third party module that does not use Error::Exception, consider

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { Exception::Class::Base->throw( error => join '', @_ ); };
```

This will transform all errors into Exception::Class objects.

[Error::Exception](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Error::Exception) sets up proper stringification for Exception::Class objects.

Comment: `eval { blah }; if($@) { blah }` is broken because `$@` can be clobbered by object destructors.  With `eval { some_code(); 1 } or do { handle_exception() };` handle_exception is guaranteed to run, but $@ may be lost.   There are still subtle traps to avoid.  That's why, if you want simple exception handling, `Try::Tiny` is a good way to go.  TT's docs go into ways that exception handling in Perl has issues.  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny  You may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/whats-broken-about-exceptions-in-perl

Comment: I've updated the answer to include Try::Tiny in case anyone new stumbles across this.