# What are the best practices for error handling in Perl?

Tags: perl, error-handling

I'm learning Perl, and in a lot of the examples I see errors are handled like this

```
open FILE, "file.txt" or die $!;
```

Is `die` in the middle of a script really the best way to deal with an error?

Comment: For discussions of perl exceptions, see [What's broken about exceptions in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/whats-broken-about-exceptions-in-perl), [Do you use an exception class in your Perl programs? Why or why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439966/do-you-use-an-exception-class-in-your-perl-programs-why-or-why-not), and [Object-oriented exception handling in Perl -- is it worth it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503189/object-oriented-exception-handling-in-perl-is-it-worth-it)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Whether `die` is appropriate in the middle of the script really depends on what you're doing. If it's only tens of lines, then it's fine.  A small tool with a couple hundred lines, then consider confess (see below). If it's a large object-oriented system with lots of classes and interconnected code, then maybe an exception object would be better.

confess in the [Carp](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Carp-1.26/lib/Carp.pm) package:
Often the bug that led to the die isn't on the line that die reports.
Replacing die with confess (see Carp package) will give the stack trace (how we got to this line) which greatly aids in debugging.

For handling exceptions from Perl builtins, I like to use [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/autodie/lib/autodie.pm). It catches failures from `open` and other system calls and will throw exceptions for you, without having to do the `or die` bit. These exceptions can be caught with a `eval { }`, or better yet, by using [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~nuffin/Try-Tiny/lib/Try/Tiny.pm).

Comment: I've always thought they should call it `autoOrDie` :)

Comment: @friedo It would look to much like `authorDie` :)

Answer (score 15):

Since I use [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log::Log4perl) almost everywhere, I use `$logger->logdie` instead of `die`. And if you want to have more control over your exceptions, consider [Exception::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception::Class).

It is better to catch your exceptions with [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny) (see its documentation why).

Answer (score 7):

Unless you've got a more specific idea, then *yes* you want to die when unexpected things happen.

- Dying at the failure to open a file and giving the file name is better than the system telling you it can't read from or write to an anonymous undefined.
- If you're talking about a "script", in general you're talking about a pretty simple piece of code. Not layers that need coordination (not usually). In a Perl *Module*, there is an attendant idea is that you don't own the execution environment, so either the main software cares and it catches things in an eval, OR it doesn't really care and dying would be fine. However, one you should try at a little more robustness as a module and just pass back undefs or something.
- You can catch whatever dies (or croaks) in an eval block. And you can do your more specific handling there.
- But if you want to inspect $! then *write that code*, and you'll have a more specific resolution.
- Take a look at the near-universal standard of using `strict`. That's code that dies on questionable syntax, rather than letting you continue along.

So I think the general idea is: *yes, **DIE*** unless you have a better idea of how things should be handled. If you put enough foresight into it, you can be forgiven for the one or two times you don't die, because you *know* you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

The more modern approach is to use the Carp standard library.

```
use Carp;
my $fh;
open $fh, '<', "file.txt" or confess($!);
```

The main advantage is it gives a stack trace on death.

Comment: Well, croak doesn't give a stack trace unless you set some other Carp things.

Comment: Carps typically don't confess, either. However, there *is* a fish called a croaker on the east coast of the USA. But, they aren't carp.

Comment: since this is Perl that sort of makes perfect sense.  ;)

Comment: @SystematicFrank Carps croak when they die -- they're more verbose than the standard fish.

Answer (score 1):

I use die but I wrap it in eval blocks for control over the error handling:

```
my $status = eval
{
    # Some code...
};
```

If the 'eval' fails:

1. `$status` will be undefined.
2. `$@` will be set to whatever error message was produced (or the contents of
   a `die`)

If the 'eval' succeeds:

1. `$status` will be the last returned value of the block.
2. `$@` will be set to ''.

Comment: There are a ton of problems with `eval {}` that need obscure work-arounds.  Use Try::Tiny instead.  It wraps up all the noxious boilerplate in a clean, easy to use package.

Comment: There are a ton of problems with `eval {}` that need obscure work-arounds... if you care about identifying the error. If you're going to take the same action regardless of its cause, a simple block `eval` works fine. But, yeah: Use `Try::Tiny` in all other cases.

Comment: I'll try that out next time I write some Perl. I use this way to fake a try-catch (by adding a check of $@ after the eval block.)  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

As @friedo wrote, if this is a standalone script of a few lines, die is fine, but in my opinion using die in modules or require'd piece of code is not a good idea because it interrupts the flow of the program. I think the control of the flow should be a prerogative of the main part of the program.

Thus, I think, in module it is better to return undef such as `return` which would return undef in scalar context and an empty list in list context and set an Exception object to be retrieved for more details. This concept is implemented in the module [Module::Generic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Generic) like this:

```
# in some module
sub myfunc
{
  my $self = shift( @_ );
  # some code...
  do{ # something } or return( $self->error( "Oops, something went wrong." ) );
}
```

Then, in the caller, you would write:

```
$obj->myfunc || die( "An error occurred at line ", $obj->error->line, " with stack trace: ", $obj->error->trace );
```

Here `error` will set an exception object and return undef.

However, because many module `die` or `croak`, you also need to catch those interruption using [eval](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#eval-EXPR) or try-catch blocks such as with [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try)

Full disclosure: I am the developer of both Module::Generic and Nice::Try.